# \smalltriangleright not working in algpseudocodex

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I'm using the [`algpseudocodex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex) package to display pseudocode in LuaLaTeX. I want to change the symbol at the beginning of a comment to `\smalltriangleright` with:

```
\usepackage[beginComment=$\smalltriangleright$~]{algpseudocodex}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...{beginComment=$\smalltriangleright 
                                                  $~}][{}]\noexpand \@pkgext...
l.9
```

It works fine with `\triangleright`, which is the default. Also, in the document, `\smalltriangleright` works as expected.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage[beginComment=$\smalltriangleright$~]{algpseudocodex} % doesn't work
%\usepackage[beginComment=$\triangleright$~]{algpseudocodex} % works

\begin{document}
$\smalltriangleright$ % works
\end{document}
```

(Tested on Overleaf, TeX Live 2021)

Any ideas on how I can get `\smalltriangleright` to work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To  make it work  you need to  re-set the default symbols for begin short comment, begin long comment, and end long comment.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math} 

\usepackage{algpseudocodex} 

%****************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
\setkeys{algpx}{beginComment=$\smalltriangleright$~}
\setkeys{algpx}{beginLComment=$\smalltriangleright$~}
\setkeys{algpx}{endLComment=~$\smalltriangleleft$}  
%******************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $x \gets y^2$
    \LComment{The next two lines increment
         both $x$ and $y$.}
    \State $x \gets x + 1$
    \Comment{Increment $x$.}
    \State $y \gets y + 1$
    \Comment{Increment $y$.}
\end{algorithmic}
\bigskip

\begin{algorithmic}% keep the changes local <<<<<
    \setkeys{algpx}{beginComment=//~}
    \setkeys{algpx}{beginLComment=/*~}
    \setkeys{algpx}{endLComment=~*/}        
    \LComment{Long comment.}
    \State $x \gets 0$ \Comment{Short comment.}
\end{algorithmic}
    
\end{document}
```

You may want to keep changes locally.

```
\begin{algorithmic}
    \setkeys{algpx}{beginComment=//~}
    \setkeys{algpx}{beginLComment=/*~}
    \setkeys{algpx}{endLComment=~*/}        
    \LComment{Long comment.}
    \State $x \gets 0$ \Comment{Short comment.}
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image: b]

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found another answer.

I realized that `unicode-math` defines `\smalltriangleright` (and other symbols) in `\AtBeginDocument`. From the [docs](https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf):

> *unicode-math* defines the macros by `\AtBeginDocument`, namely delays the definition until `\begin{document}` is met.

Therefore, loading `algpseudocodex` afterwards works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\usepackage[beginComment=$\smalltriangleright$~]{algpseudocodex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \State $x \gets 0$ \Comment{Short comment.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```